# How to send URL scheme to telegram so user can click it

Tags: url, telegram, telegram-bot, url-scheme

I am making a bot, and bot needs to send user a URL scheme : `appname://product?pId=(blahblah)`

I was tring using as Markdown, I have send Like this : `[Open App](appname://product?pId=(blahblah)` and what I got in message is `Open App` without link.
also, just sending `appname://product?pId=(blahblah)` does not set as URL, just like a normal message, so I can't open it in the message.

Is there is any way to send that app link to telegram message and user just click to open?